# Decimales en un DataFame

Tags: python, dataframe, decimal

Tengo 2 listas, una de ellas, con 1 número decimal y 5 número enteros.

```
lista_consumo=[49.259, 13, 86, 120, 1453, 0]
lista_llamada=["Internet","Contestador","Fijo","Interna a fijo","Interna a móvil","Móvil"]
```

Cuando creo un DataFrame con estas listas, a los números enteros se les añaden tantos decimales como tenga el número decimal.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lista_llamada,lista_consumo)),columns = ['Tipo de llamada','Cantidad'])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? Qué problema tienes con esta situación? Por favor, ve a [edit] y especifica qué necesitas que sea diferente a lo que describes.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.